# Add class inside another element via javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a class to a class to a specific element, that is in another element via javascript. In my case I have a div with the class "jet-woo-product-thumbnail" inside this div I have a linked image inside an a-tag like this

```
<div class="jet-woo-product-thumbnail">
  <a href="https://example.com" rel="bookmark">
    <img width="300" height="300" src="https://example.com/image.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="">
  </a>
```

Now i need to add the class to the hyperlink element like:

```
<div class="jet-woo-product-thumbnail">
  <a href="https://example.com" class="my_class" rel="bookmark">
    <img width="300" height="300" src="https://example.com/image.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt=""></a>
```

I tried:

```
jQuery('div.jet-woo-product-thumbnail').find('a').addClass('my_class');
```

but this did not work. Is there any error.

Comment: Try  $('.jet-woo-product-thumbnail a').addClass('class')

Comment: "Did not work" is not a sufficient description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jquery-find-in-a-doc-addclass?file=index.html

You used it in a doc ready function, like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('div.jet-woo-product-thumbnail').find('a').addClass('my_class');
});
```

Make sure you've closed the div tag correctly. In your example code it is not closed:

```
<div class="jet-woo-product-thumbnail">
...
</div>
```

Otherwise jquery will not work.